# display icons with black overlay on top right corner of image css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying images using jquery lightbox slider, the lightbox slider dynamically inserts image into lightbox-container. i would like to have a heart icon on image to mark it as favorite. how could i use css to position icons with black overlay on top right corner of image.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the relevant code..? are we supposed to create a slider from scratch or use our sixth sense to visualize your markup..? O.o

Comment: Yes we know you have it running, the question is, in order to help you, are we supposed to make a slider from the scratch and play with it? since you have it already, can't you simply post the code or share a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help the ones trying to help you..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code, here's a basic CSS and HTML for a general case.

CSS:

```
.sliderImgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-top: 50px solid #000000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
.overlayImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sliderImgWrapper">
    <div class="overlay">
        <img class="overlayImage" src="src_of_img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6V85W/). (I didn't have a heart stored at imgur, but `+` will do...)